# JPA QueryException - A reference class must be provided

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Using JPA 2.0, Java EE 5, Weblogic 10.3 (11g), JDK 6, EclipseLink.

When i attempt to run this:

```
 CriteriaQuery _criteriaquery = EM.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Clazz);
        Query query = EM.createQuery(_criteriaquery);
        return query.getResultList();
```

I just get this :

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6029] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
    Exception Description: A reference class must be provided.
    Query: ReportQuery()
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.referenceClassMissing(QueryException.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkDescriptor(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:744)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
```

What could be the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't complited. You should add `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses.

```
CriteriaQuery<SomeEntity> _criteriaquery = EM.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(SomeEntity.class);
Root<SomeEntity> selector = _criteriaquery.from(SomeEntity.class); // FROM
_criteriaquery.select(selector);  // SELECT
Query query = EM.createQuery(_criteriaquery);
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I thought putting a variable of type Class was enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
CriteriaQuery _criteriaquery = EM.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Clazz.class);
```

instead of

```
CriteriaQuery _criteriaquery = EM.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Clazz);
```

Comment: If the code compiles, then `Clazz` is a variable: `Class<?> Clazz = Object.class`. The correct would be to write it with lowercase, but it's not really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The same exception can also be thrown if you forget to register your class in `persistence.xml`.